# Building plots from user input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plot, architecture

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application in which users can design questions, and questions may contain graphs. However, charts aren't saved as images, but are described in a text format, since they may contain variables that the application evaluates.

An example question may be:

> What is the slope of the next function? && Polynomial -5 5 -5 5 2 1 &&

Now, whenever the application displays the question, it looks for special text (Wrapped in "&&"), which in this case, means: Build a chart, with x-axis going from -5 to 5, y-axis going from -5 to 5, and plot the polynomial y=2x+1.

Right now, this works. I have a kind of factory that reads the first word ("Polynomial") and creates a new instance of the PolynomialChart class (which inherits from Chart), passing all the other information as constructor parameters. Another example would be

> && VerticalLine -5 5 -5 5 1 &&

Which would produce an instanco of the VerticalLineChart.

However, I realized that often, users will want to add new constraints, like: "Dont show the grid for the plot", so I would design a command that would look like this:

> && PolynomialNoGrid -5 5 -5 5 2 1 &&

And would implement a new class called PolynomialNoGridChart, and the process would be the same.

I realize that this isn't very scalable, since every little difference in every chart would force me to build new classes. I've been thinking about changing the structure of the commands to include different attributes, such as

> && Polynomial -5 5 -5 5 grid:false 2 1 &&

But I'm not liking the way this looks; makes me think it will make things complicated when trying to parse the command. Another option I've been considering is using an XML format:

```
<chart minx="-5" maxx="5" miny="-5" maxy="5" grid="false" >
     <polynomial coefs="2,1" \>
     <polynomial coefs="3,1" domain-start="4" \>
     <verticalline x="2" \>
<\chart>
```

This clearly gives me a way to describe objects in an organized way, plus, it gives me a way of including several plots, which is another type of graph (currently MultiPolynomialChart)

My question is: Am I apporaching the problem correctly? It seems like I may be overcomplicationg things. Also, is there a pattern I should follow to analyze suxh XML files and process them?

Comment: You are seeking for a 'small language'. As usual you need to decide on a vocabulary and a grammar. Also: you need to discern between ui and processing. ui is best menu-driven; processing best with key-value pairs. You started with positional params. This is not going very far, I'd say.. -  you will necessarily meet contradictory forces/goals. Simplicty va extensibility; simple input vs simple processing etc.. no silver bullets. still: think biggly ;-)